# Xcode Archive Error: clang: error: no such file or directory

Tags: ios, xcode, build, archive, build-error

I am currently trying to archive my project in Xcode and I am running into a build error that says:

> clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/solar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-exafbzcdrpuigiaqxbhhlirzwpsu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphonesimulator/il2cpp.a'

Does anyone here know what's going on? I looked the error up online and didn't find anything useful, as I am only using Xcode to build my project and I am not using things like Flutter or Swift. Please help!